# Anime/cartoon of people who draws/writes characters (as in language characters) to summon monsters

Tags: story-identification

It's this old show I used to watch on TV back at Taiwan. From what I remember, the main character uses a machine to swipe something and then draws/writes many chinese/japanese characters in the air, summoning a spirit or monster that might have been a wolf. The main antagonist can summon a tiger or lion. There are many different stages these spirit/monsters can go into that makes them more powerful, like evolving in Pokemon but it's temporarily.

Thanks!